# If 200kg/s mass flow rate of LNG is feasible in a heat exchanger?

Tags: heat-exchanger

Here is the situation: In a shell and tube condenser, the hot shell side is Pentane from 115°C to 36°C and the cold tube side is LNG at the temperature of -161℃ at the inlet of the heat exchanger. The mass flow rate of Pentane is 1kg/s.

So based on energy conservation, with the outlet temperature of LNG I can calculate the mass flow rate of the LNG.

But I find that at the case when the temperature change of LNG is small(less than 1°C), the LNG mass flow rate is very big(more than 200kg/s).
I wonder If 200kg/s is feasible in practice?

Comment: There is no mass exchange between the two fluids.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There are insufficient constraints to make a mass flow rate impossible.  Calculate what size passage you would need for your desired flow rate instead.

Comment: What is the outlet temperature for LNG?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Possible but not likely

At temperature changes less than 1 degree C you are dividing by a fraction.  Make that fraction small enough and you get a huge flow rate from the equation.

In the real world, the flow rates of the LNG will be limited by the physical characteristics of the exchanger, and it is extemely unlikely anyone would build a heat exchanger big enough to pass such a flow rate to change temperature of the LNG by a fraction of a degree.  We can build a heat exchanger to pass almost any conceivable flow rate with enough money, but the question would be why.

Comment: Saturn V's F1s burned 2578kg/s each, but needed a 55,000hp fuel pump.